# What build step should the artifactory plugin be activated for?

Tags: teamcity, artifactory

I'm using the Artifactory plugin for TeamCity to store artifacts from our builds. The plugin, however, does some things that seem to me to be quite odd, and not TeamCity-ish at all.

The plugin adds a new section to the settings for each build step in my build configuration. This section allows me to specify artifacts to be stored in Artifactory. What is odd, however, is that these settings are particular to each build step; this means that if my build has two build steps, and I set up the first build step to store artifacts, and then view the settings for the second build step, the plugin will not appear to be configured there.

Further confusing the issue is that [the documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/TeamCity+Artifactory+Plug-in) specifies that the plugin works with "most" build runner types, and lists several examples: "Maven2, Maven 3, Ivy/Ant (with Ivy modules support), Gradle , NAnt, MSBuild, FxCop and Ipr."

My question is, then, which build step should I configure Artifactory for? What if I configure it for a build step that isn't on the list of "working" build runners? Why does the plugin allow/require me to configure it multiple times?

It seems to me that the Artifactory plugin should instead add a new build runner, i.e. "Deploy artifacts to Artifactory", which would give me one supported place to configure it.

Answer (score 3):

The TeamCity Artifactory Plugin indeed allows you to attach artifacts deployment, as part of specific steps, instead of the approach of providing one deployment step. One of the reasons for this implementation is to allow different deployment methods, depending on the build tool or technology you're using. For example, when using Gradle, the Artifactory Plugin uses Gradle's APIs deploy the artifacts, thus providing a native method for deployment.

Another reason is more flexibility in terms of when in your workflow the deployment should occur. In the common scenario, you'd like your artifacts to be deployed to Artifactory at the end of the build, but that is not always the case. Sometimes you'd like one step, for example a command line step, to run a script that performs a specific job, that results in specific artifacts deployed and tagged in Artifactory. Then you'd like a second step, to consume those artifacts as dependencies and deploy new artifacts to Artifactory. I guess that adding an additional "Artifactory Deployment" step is possible and this is something that can be added in the future. JFrog CLI has become very popular recently and can be easily embedded as a command line step to download, upload and publish build-info to Artifactory.

So to answer your question as for which build step you should use with Artifactory, this is up to you and your needs. There are many ways you can plan your build pipeline to work, and I think you should go for the way that makes the most sense for your workflow. 
I hope this answers your question.